# Laravel project in production

Tags: php, laravel

I just pushed my laravel project in the ftp, but when I go on the right link, it returns me the same error as when no file was in this ftp.

What are the steps to follow to be able to make a laravel projet open running online.

I'm sure that I missed a step but I don't know which one.

I just changed these to lines of the .env file :

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: To me that sound more like a server problem. Did you try to get a blank laravel project running? My guess is that something with your htaccess or directory access is wrong. Can you post the error you are referring to?

Comment: "Error 403 - Forbidden" It's possible, I never tried to run the blank Laravel project indeed...

Comment: walk through the install procedure to get the file and directory permissions right first - hope this gonna fix your production site...

Comment: Shall I put the permissions towards public/index.php to 777 ?

Comment: It may be lack of permission in the folder, lack of permission to execute .htaccess directives or a number of things. Check the Apache Logs for possible directions on what is causing this.

Comment: can you provide the directory structure of your App in the FTP site?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work, thanks to @Kjells tips.

I had to redirect the webpage towards public/